# Can't get overlays to show on own testing app

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

EDIT: Man this is awkward, MKer is right, I corrected the code and now can see the ScaleBar. No luck yet with the my location issue.

I have been trying for a few days and I'm starting to pull my hair. Noob at Android and Osmdroid.

I can build and have done so, with success, osmdroid demo apps. Also tried the OSMbonuspack and had the navigator working with the "find me" overlay, scale, etc.

Problem is whenever I make my own app, the only overlay that shows up and works in my map is the compass. I guess I am doing something wrong but can't find any info on the subject.

I have tested this with Genymotion virtual devices (there not even the compass shows) amd my 6.0 mobile where compass works, but no MyLocation or even Scale.

I have given the app permissions, and all I see in the android log are messages about tiles loading when moving the map. Plus this error which I haven't found much info about except in chinese.

> E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 113 "1"

Any help welcome!

Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anemptyappmap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.anemptyappmap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.constants.OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ScaleBarOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.compass.CompassOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.compass.InternalCompassOrientationProvider;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.GpsMyLocationProvider;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.MyLocationNewOverlay;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Vars para mapa
    private MyLocationNewOverlay mLocationOverlay;
    private CompassOverlay mCompassOverlay=null;
    //private MinimapOverlay mMinimapOverlay;
    private ScaleBarOverlay mScaleBarOverlay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        String cachePath = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        org.osmdroid.tileprovider.constants.OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setCachePath(cachePath);

        //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers
        //Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));

        MapView mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mMapView);
        mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        //map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

                mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(context),mMapView);
    mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mLocationOverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);
    //mLocationOverlay.setPersonIcon();
    mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mLocationOverlay);

    mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(context, new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(context), mMapView);
    mCompassOverlay.enableCompass();
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mCompassOverlay);

    mScaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(mMapView);
    mScaleBarOverlay.setScaleBarOffset(dm.widthPixels / 2, 10);
    mScaleBarOverlay.setCentred(true);
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mScaleBarOverlay);

    //this.mScaleBarOverlay.setAlignBottom(true);
    //this.mScaleBarOverlay.setCentred(true);
    this.mScaleBarOverlay.enableScaleBar();

        //this.mMinimapOverlay = new MinimapOverlay();

        IMapController mapController = mMapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(13);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(43.3600, -8.2800);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
       // mMapView.invalidate();
    }
}
```

And the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.anemptyappmap.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/crossfade_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/mMapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You don't see the scalebar because you don't add it to map overlays (as you do for Compass). For MyLocationNewOverlay, I don't know.

Comment: Well thanks a lot! I thought I had checked it but now I can see the scale bar. Have edited the code accordingly. Still no luck with location overlay!

Comment: Just an update, I haven't been able to show the location overlay on my phone, _but_ it shows fine in a Genymotion 4.4 device. So I guess it's some weird stuff going on. What I did is use MKer's osmdroidbonuspack library, and following his example app I have been able to get the location working on any device.